# npm run build no me guarda cambios

Tags: reactjs

Eso, por mas que haga cambios en mi proyecto, cuando hago npm run build y npm run deploy, los cambios no se ven reflejados en la pagina.

```
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

Ayer funcionaba y hoy ya no...

Comment: Podría ser que a la hora de deployar no suba sus cambios, que herramienta usa para hacer su deploy ?

Comment: @wootsbot Perdón no se a que se refiere, solo uso la dependencia gh-pages y ejecuto npm run deploy desde la terminal integrada de vsc